# Find a book with reference number and issued date with Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Find a book with reference number and issued date.

I creating books store with ruby on rails, user type reference number and issued date display books only, this not a search function.

```
t.integer reference
t.datetime "created_at"
```

How can possible work with simple_form gem.

Comment: question is not clear, please explain what are trying to achieve using simple_form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Book.where(reference: number, created_at: date).first`

Comment: Not sure that even you understand your question